# Earliest service group that user mode applications can use in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows, there are a lot of different groups for services. the earliest one is System reserved.

So can user mode services use any of them? or is there a limit for user mode applications?

For example i wrote a test app that writes/reads files, obviously this shouldn't work in the first group (System reserved) since file system drivers are not yet loaded (?), but it does work, so i thought maybe Windows is not executing it in that group since its a user mode app?

Comment: you how minimum 3 time ask the same question. what is sense in "earliest" start ?

Comment: @RbMm They are completely different.. This question is simple, which service group can uesr mode services use that is as early as possible in windows boot? obviously file system drivers and other essential drivers need to be loaded already.

Comment: question is unclear. real question - what you really need ?

Comment: @RbMm I need my service to start as early as possible for a user-mode service.

Comment: for what ? answer depend from this

Comment: @RbMm this is a user-mode disinfector, i don't have a certificate for signing drivers. I need my service to start before the malware's service so i can delete its file before it hides it with its driver.

Comment: @RbMm i tried to set the group to system reserved, but still the service of the malware seems to start earlier ( it doesnt have a group). my question is, can user mode applications even use groups like system reserved? considering it is earlier than filesystem group